# Exportar datagrid a PDF y dejar una fila entera para un dato

Tags: c#, datagrid

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy exportando un `Datagrid` a PDF con `iTextSharp`. Funciona todo bien, pero necesito darle el espacio de una fila entera a un dato que es largo.

Por ejemplo:

> Registro 1: id= 1, nombre ="Pedro", apellido ="Perez", descripcion= "Esta es la descripcion de pedro y es muy larga".

Necesito que `id`, `nombre` y `apellido` estén en la fila 1, y en la fila de abajo este la descripción. Así con todos los registros que compongan la tabla! Alguno tiene idea como hacer eso?

Quiero que parteEncontrado este abajo de el primer registro(y ocupe toda la columna)

Comment: Por favor déjanos un ejemplo de lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte, sino, es probable que tu pregunta termine cerrada por demasiado amplia..

Comment: Ahi lo edite @JuanSalvadorPortugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin conocer tu codigo de como exportas tus datos a PDF es dificil ayudarte como tu pretendes, sin embargo tuve una situacion similar como la que tienes y obtuve la solucion, aclaro que mi caso fue con `Windows Form` y `DataGridView` pero  usando la libreria `iTextSharp`.

De entrada pienso te puede servir un poco la forma en que se resolvió (Si esque entendí lo que requieres), No creo que sea la mejor solucíon pero si resuelve la problematica y te la comparto.

Basicamente lo que hago es obtener las columnas de mi datagridview(en este caso son 11, adaptando a los datos de tu problema). Con

```
datatable.SetWidths(new float[] { 10, 10, 25, 10, 30, 20, 15, 10, 30, 20, 0 });
```

estoy definiendo el ancho de cada columna y si te das cuenta al ultimo le pongo un cero (0), esto es porque en primera instancia, solo queremos mostrar los datos de las primeras 10 columnas y la última columna que no sea visible.

Con `PdfPCell` declaramos una celda que va imprimiendo todas las columas (en este caso de mi dgv)  *De echo imprime hasta la columna 11 pero como el ultimo tiene un ancho de 0 no es visible el dato*

Al ultimo comparamos que si la columna es 10 (recordar que el ciclo for empieza de 0)
entonces se vuelva a crear una nueva celda y ahí se almacene el dato de la columna 11, que en tu ejemplo seria **"parteEncontrado"**, 
Combinamos todas las columnas como si fuera un excel con la instruccion `celda1.Colspan = 11;`

y con eso se obtiene un resultado como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Anexo el código completo.**

```
private void exportarPDF(Document doc)
{
    PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(DataGridView1.ColumnCount);
    datatable.SetWidths(new float[] { 10, 10, 25, 10, 30, 20, 15, 10, 30, 20, 0 });   //Un DGV de 11 columnas, no mostrar la ultima columna (para ello, colocar 0).
    datatable.WidthPercentage = 100;
    datatable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= DataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
        {
            // Solo muestra la  columna 1 hasta la columna 10
            PdfPCell celda = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()));
            celda.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            datatable.AddCell(celda);

            if (j == 10)
            {
                // Mostrar la columna 11
                PdfPCell celda1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(DataGridView1(10, i).Value.ToString()));
                celda1.Colspan = 11;
                celda1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                celda1.PaddingBottom = 15;
                datatable.AddCell(celda1);
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Add(datatable);
}
```